# SSO Setup for a Saas Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am looking for some advice regarding **"SSO"** Setup.

My development team is building a `reactjs+node js` `Saas Application.

Within this application, we will provide an Option so the user can set up an `SSO SAML Authnicaiton` by providing

```
idP metadata

Entity ID

Binding location

Adding Certificate
```

I have tried to use several services like `auth0` but these are extremely expensive services to use. Do any of you know any service which can be set very easily and very cost consciously?

Comment: Datawiza provides a cost-effective solution to this. https://www.datawiza.com/saas-sso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few open-source alternatives you can try.

1. [Node SAML](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-saml)
2. [SAML Jackson](https://github.com/boxyhq/jackson)

In the settings page, add a page to enter the SALM metadata.

On the login page, ask the users to enter their company email address or tenant id and redirect the users to IdP based on that.